# Update parent record with read only permission when there is a update in child record(full-access)

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, sharing

I have a requirement to update parent record when there is a update on child record.

Suppose there is a Account with "Read-Only" permission and on a Opportunity with Full-Access, when I change the status of the opportunity, I should be able to update the account record as well.

Can this be achieved in any ways?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that these permission are controlled by profile, so it is hard to bypass them, may be you can use permission sets to give user temp permission like: 
based on some value put the Owner of Account into a Queue and give it Read/Write permission to Account Owner.